# SQL to concatenate two columns and join two tables

Tags: sql

Table `person`:

```
| id | f_name | l_name |
```

Table `sales`:

```
| id | amount | date | itemname |
```

I have a problem joining the two tables which concat `f_name` and `last_name` as fullname column, and joining with table sales. Here `id` is same on both tables.

Output:

```
| itemname| date |fullname |
```

What I have tried:

```
select * 
from
    (select 
         concat(f_name, l_name) as fullname 
     from 
         tblperson) p 
left join
    select itemname, date 
    from table sales s on s.id = p.id
```

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Answer (score 1):

It should actually be

```
SELECT table_sales.*, concat(table_person.f_name, table_person.l_name) as fullname
FROM table_person
LEFT JOIN table_sales
ON table_person.id = table_sales.id
```

have not tested this but that is the syntax

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a field like person_id in your sales table (which references the id field in the person table). You can then use a join to properly join the data together.

Answer (score 0):

You are so close. Try this

```
select p.*,concat(f_name,l_name)as fullname, s.itemname,s.date, s.amount
    from person p left join
    sales  s on s.id=p.id
```

Here ia good read on sql join.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp